# GPG: [unknown] in a showpref output?

Tags: gnupg, gpg4win, kleopatra

I'm inspecting **my** key pair by `showpref` and get something like this:

> ```
> [ unknown] (1). user@mail.server <user@mail.server>
>      Cipher: AES256, AES, AES192, 3DES
>      AEAD:
>      Digest: SHA256, SHA512, SHA1
>      Compression: Uncompressed, ZLIB, ZIP
>      Features: MDC, AEAD
>      Notations: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
> ```

I can not find the exact phrase *[unknown]* in the [manual](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg24/gpg.1.html) , but it seems that unknown means unknown trust level, judging by this section:

> TRUST VALUES Trust values are used to indicate ownertrust and validity
> of keys and user IDs. They are displayed with letters or strings:
>
> ```
> - unknown No ownertrust assigned / not yet calculated.
> e expired Trust calculation has failed; probably due to an expired key.
> q undefined, undef Not enough information for calculation.
> n never Never trust this key.
> m marginal Marginally trusted.
> f full Fully trusted.
> u ultimate Ultimately trusted.
> r revoked For validity only: the key or the user ID has been revoked.
> ? err The program encountered an unknown trust value.
> ```

If I generated this key and it in the keyring, how could the trust level be unknown ? I'm really struggling to understand this, especially since in Kleopatra the same key's trust level is Ultimate, as I understand it should be.
[image]

any Ideas of why this discrepancy happens and should I  manually change the trust level ?